# Should the names of different sorting algorithms be "<qualifier> sort" or "<qualifier>sort"?

Tags: orthography, compounds

Should the names of different sorting algorithms be `<qualifier> sort` or `<qualifier>sort`?

The titles of Wikipedia articles of these sorting algorithms are not consistent with respect to this.  See the [listing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_algorithms).  From English grammar (correction: orthography) point of view, which is better?

Comment: Like all other compounds in English, there is considerable variation. If the first member (the ‘qualifier’, as you call it in your case here) is a simple, underived noun (ideally monosyllabic), you can write your compound closed if you wish. For derived and other longer nouns, open spellings are more common. From a _grammar_ point of view, this doesn't matter an iota, because it's quite unrelated to grammar. It's orthography.

Answer (score 2):

Pedagogically algorithms sometimes have cute streamedtogether, underscore_separated or camelCase names to emphasize to students the idea they are invoked like computer code.

To my mind, those are not their real names, and most reasonable mathematicians discussing them in practice call them something that is acceptable to type in English.  One says "quicksort", rather than "quick sort", because quick is just an adjective, and this would otherwise be confusing, some people even resort to "the quicksort sort".  But I would not say "heapsort", or "bubblesort", I would say "heap sort" or "bubble sort".

Comment: So this depends on if the qualifier adjective is confusing or not?  How confusing is English as a language!

Comment: Yeah, but this has less to do with English itself, and more to do with the Anglo-American fascination with coinages and very cute names like 'quicksort', 'EZ whatsit' or 'the The'.

Comment: Whether compound words are combined is very idiosyncratic in English. Why do we write *everybody, everyone, somebody, someone, anybody, anyone, nobody*, but not *noone*? Because *no one* is less confusing.

Comment: I would question whether these are really compound words.  They just seem to be coerced nouns modifying sort.  Are beef jerky or television program compound words?  Therefore falling back on 'the quiksort sort' or even 'the heapsort heap sort' (since there are other less efficient algorithms in that general category).